# How to input data in the correct order in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, npm

I am using Node.js to send some data to a SQL Server table. The code has a for loop, which calls a function, which runs an insert statement (will eventually be a stored procedure). The foor loop runs through a series of objects, in order by date. Most of the time, the insert statements finish in the correct order but some of the entries are in the wrong order.

Is there some way to insure that the order of dates in the database is the same order as I call them (chronologically). I know about `SORT` in T-SQL, but I think the program should do it in the correct order. I have always heard to avoid thread sleeping and timers whenever possible, so I don't like the idea of `setTimeout`. Is there another way, perhaps with event handling?

Example code below. An element of the `jsonArray` is a single object that has a date key as well as several other numbers. The SQL Server table has an autoincrementing primary key integer, and I want the dates to be entered chronologically (like I call them), so that the primary key as well as the dates are in order.

I am also using the `MSSQL` import for the SQL manipulation.

```
// Main class
for (let j = 0; j < jsonArray.length; j++) {
   let myObj = jsonArray[j]
   WriteToDB.myWriteFunction(myObj)
}

// Different class    
const sql = require('mssql')
let request = new sql.Request()
let query = (...)

function myWriteFunction () {
   request.query(query) // Just the actual insert statement, no issue here
   request.on('error', function (err) {
      console.log('REQ ERROR')
      console.dir(err)
   })
// These dates are out of order, due to when the done event is triggered
   request.on('done', function () { 
      console.log('QUERY RAN FOR ' + e1)
   })
}
```

Comment: Why is the order of the records in your database important?  A primary key is intended as a unique identifier for a record, not as a sorting mechanism.

Comment: Well I suppose aside from OCD there is no reason. I am assuming its some sort of multithreading that is causing this. I had a similar program in C# that would enter all the data in the order it was passed. I just wanted to try to match that. Also just trying to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am assuming its some sort of multithreading that is causing this

those database operations are done asynchronously and they all happen on the same thread. If the D1 (first database operation) takes longer than D2 (second database operation) and D1 is inserted after the D2 (resulting you problem), it's not a problem that involves multi-threading, maybe D2 has more data, etc. ..

I would totally recommend you NOT to use the bellow code sample unless you really believe the order in the sql in indeed important. req2 is done only after req1 is finish and so on .. => wasted time

```
let jsonArray = [1,2,3,4];
if (checkArray(jsonArray)) {
  createReq(jsonArray[0])
}
function createReq(req) {
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve();
      jsonArray.shift();
      console.log(req);
      if (checkArray(jsonArray)) {
        createReq(jsonArray[0])
      }
    }, 100)
  })
}
function checkArray(arr) {
  return (jsonArray && jsonArray[0])
}
```

Comment: I have seen the light/ error of my ways. I will not be using your code, but I now see how it is possible. Thank you!